# What is a way to get a user's photos from Facebook (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, my plan is to query for a user's albums, and then iterate through those albums and get all the images. Is there a good way of skipping the albums step entirely? Here is the code I am using to get their album info:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"Results: %@", result);
                          }
                      }
 ];
```

If I could make a similar query that only gets photos, that would be perfect. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simply fetch the data through this url:

http://graph.facebook.com/philiparpin/picture

Replace philiparpin (my name) with the name of the user you want to get the photo of.

Resource:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: Doesn't this only get one picture? I'm trying to get every picture of a user so they can choose between them. A lot of apps do it (tinder for example).

Comment: How is your user list stored? Import it as an array, and then just link every picture to the FB username. Thats the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how to differentiate between different pictures with this method. I can change the username but not any photo or album IDs